# ldconfig not working for linux kernal 2.6.37.6 created with BuysBox v1.19.3

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, kernel

I created a tiny OS, and then i created a shared Library, i want to create the dynamic link of it. I followed everything from this [link](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/shared-libraries-linux-gcc.html). Everything works fine. i created `liblog.so` i putted this in my machine(in tiny os in vmware) in `/usr/lib`  then i ran `ldconfig` expecting everything would be file but  it gives this output

`ldconfig : skipping /usr/X11R6/lib No Such file or directory`.

When i googled about this problem i found even i didn't had `/etc/ld.so.conf also /etc/ld.so.conf.d/` in my machine.

when i ran `ldconfig -p | grep lib` it shows me `Library Cache Disabled`. 
Why this is happening i am not able to crate the link.

when i run `ldd log_clien` Here `log_client` is going to use the `liblog.so`.

```
checking sub-depends for '/usr/lib/liblog/so'
checking sub-depends for 'not found'
liblog.so => /usr/lib/liblog.so (0x00000000)
libc.so.6 => notfound (0x00000000)
not a dynamic executable
```

Is there any alternate way to make links or, Please help me to fix this. 
I want to use the shared library system, because this is going to be used by many codes.

Comment: Did you try adding ldconfig file to /etc/ld.so.conf.d/ and run ldconfig?

Comment: Sorry @Sasi I didn't got you !! are you asking to add `liblog.so` to `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/`. I added(`liblog.so`) to folder `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/` and ran `ldconfig` but still it's giving me same error !!! :( (That first error)